# C++ weird compilation error on removing a variable

Tags: c++

Following code doesn't [*compile*](http://ideone.com/vibPoc) <sup>***g++ 4.8.1***</sup>

```
struct Layers
{
    typedef struct Widgets { } Widgets;

    virtual void fun(void) 
    {
        struct Widgets w;
    }

    Widgets w, x, y, z ;
};
```

However, if I just use `Widgets w, x, y ; //Remove variable z` it [*compiles*](http://ideone.com/0HRrbM) !

Why is this happening ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: it compiles for me under clang++ 4.2

Comment: @rano Yeah, I too [tried](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84b2de847d475a0c) just now !

Comment: It works if you give the typedef a different name. For eg `typedef struct Widgets { } Widgets_;`

Comment: This is very interesting, does anyone know about a way to explore deeper what the g++ parser is doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a bug in GCC

Ref: -[*Bug 46206 - using typedef-name error with typedef name hiding struct name*](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46206)

> G++ rejects the following code:
>
> ```
> class Foo
> {
>     bool a, b, c, d;
>     typedef struct Bar { } Bar;
>     virtual void foo(void) {
>         struct Bar bar;
>     }
> };    
> example.cc: In member function ‘virtual void Foo::foo()’:
> example.cc:6: error: using typedef-name ‘Foo::Bar’ after ‘struct’
> example.cc:4: error: ‘Foo::Bar’ has a previous declaration here
> example.cc:6: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
> ```
>
> but accepts many similar examples, including:
>
> ```
> class Foo
> {
>     bool a, b, c;
>     typedef struct Bar { } Bar;
>     virtual void foo(void) {
>         struct Bar bar;
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> This behaviour is reproducible on x86_64-redhat-linux (4.1.2 and 4.4.0) and i386-pc-solaris2.11 (4.2.4, 4.3.4 and 4.5.1)
>
> I'm uncertain if this is strictly legal or not per the standard, but it doesn't seem to make sense to accept one of these cases but not the other...

This appears to be fixed in latest ***GCC 4.9.0***

Comment: lol, there's an example just like yours. This could be a good way to farm reputation : D

Comment: @rano Seriously I still don't know the real problem, just happen to search similar bug on bugzilla

Comment: I'm not sure if it's fixed in 4.9.0 (I don't have an install of that yet). The last comment by Paolo Carlini was that he reverted the patch.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Even more strange he claims it only worked on linux. That makes me think that gcc is internally invoking UB somewhere...

Answer (score 7):

That's because you `typedef`'d the structure `Widgets`, check the error out:

`error: using typedef-name 'Layers::Widgets' after 'struct'`

So, the workaround is to remove the `struct` in the function.  Summing it up to:

```
struct Layers
{
    typedef struct Widgets { } Widgets;

    virtual void fun(void) 
    {
        Widgets w;
    }

    Widgets w, x, y, z ;
};

int main() { }
```

Read more about this here: [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612476#612476)

Comment: This does not explain why removing `,z' makes the code compile

Comment: The weirdness is that removal `, z` fix things :) Looks like a language parser /feature/ (somewhat similar to a bug)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why removing `z` would make it work.  Didn't take into account while posting this answer.

Comment: @user3159253 it's mostly a bug, yep.  Should try with another compiler to make sure

Comment: @P0W: I don't see the behavior that removing `z` removes the error.  Are you saying that the error is on the `struct Widgets w;` declaration in `fun()` and that removing `z` from the latter declaration makes it so there's no longer an error om the declaration in `fun()`? Like I said - I can't repro that, and it doesn't make sense to boot.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It turned out to be a GCC(4.8.1) parser bug.  Are you trying with another version?

Comment: gcc 4.2.1 seems affected as well

Comment: I'm trying on `gcc (tdm64-2) 4.8.1` (a MinGW build running on Windows, but I'd think that the parser should be the same across all 4.8.1 GCC versions).

Comment: Well - I take all that back. I had pasted the snippet into a little 'hello world' program and wasn't able to repro the behavior. When I tried compiling the snippet with nothing else, I got the repro.  Strange bug.

Comment: @MichaelBurr See OP's answer, seems like it was fixed in 4.9.0